# How to check if an input string already exists in a SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

I have a SQLite database with a list of all airports in the world with their respective data (code, country, name, etc). I'm trying to create a method where an ATC will login with their airport's code. The program will then check if the airport code exists, and return true so the ATC can login and will be able to see all the information of their airport. If it doesn't exist, it returns false and doesn't let the ATC login.

I'm trying to see if a specific "item" exists in the database, not a row or column.

By looking online this is the "closest" I've gotten, but I'm getting an error and can't figure out how else to do it right now.

```
String selectSQL = "IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE code = " + ATCLogin + ")";
```

The error I'm getting now is

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "'MAD'": syntax error)
```

"MAD" is the airport code I'm testing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the raw SQL query you want would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE code = ?)
```

Note that the above query should return a single boolean true/false value.  The `?` is a placeholder, to which you should bind a Java string value.  Here is how you can do that with a Java prepared statement.

```java
String sql = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE code = ?)";
String code = "LAX";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, code);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    boolean result = rs.getBoolean(1);
    String output = "Airport code " + code + " exists in database? " + result;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks it worked flawlessly. I've been bashing my head at this for hours with no solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio I've been banging my head for hours trying to find a question worth answering, and I found yours.  Thanks to you as well `:-)`

Comment: hah wow. Well glad I was able to give you something to do.